# Marca de agua JPEG BACKEND WEB

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, backend

Buen dia a todos, Mi pregunta o solicitud de ayuda quiza pueda parecer un poco ambigua, Estoy tratando de meterle marcas de agua a imagenes que tengo guardadas en mi servidor,

1. Tengo un REQUEST que se solicita desde el FRONT ($ajax) y el respond me trae varias imagenes en base64,

Lo que intento hacer es que la marca de agua se genere desde el back, o que me explique como usarlo desde el front recibiendo esas imagenes en base64,

Uso PHP en el back, ya leí la documentación de GD pero no me queda muy claro lo que hago es

El back trae la imagen guardad la trasforma y mete la marca de agua y la guardo en otro archivo, la solicito la codifico a BASE 64 y luego la mando en el respond. (borro el archivo creado con marca de agua terminando el proceso).

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: que codigo muestro, si lo que quiro que me expliquen con un ejemplo como funcian el GD

Comment: Como diría Black panther, _aquí no hacemos eso_.  Trata de hacer una prueba de concepto simple con un script básico que cargue una imagen y luego aplique la marca de agua. Ahí verás qué errores, problemas o dudas quedan y lo puedes traer acá para aclarar esas dudas y resolver esos errores. :)